# Problem with freezed / build_runner in plain dart package: "dart run" command not available

Tags: dart, freezed, build-runner

I am trying to use the freezed package inside a plain dart package - NO flutter!

I am following the instructions at https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#run-the-generator .

My pubspec.yaml:

```
...
version: 1.0.0
# homepage: https://www.example.com
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.17.5 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  bloc: ^8.0.3
  freezed_annotation: ^2.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^2.2.0
  freezed: ^2.1.0+1
  lints: ^2.0.0
  mockito: ^5.3.0
  test: ^1.16.0
```

My example class:

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'person.freezed.dart';

@freezed
class Person with _$Person {
  const factory Person({
    required String firstName,
    required String lastName,
  }) = _Person;
}
```

But when I call

```
dart run build_runner build
```

I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception:
Could not load "file:///{my_project_path}/run": FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '{my_project_path}//run' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
null
```

The same result when I use the run build command from the freezed vs code extension:

```
Running `dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`
Current working folder: `{my_project_path}`

Unhandled exception:
Could not load "file:///{my_project_path}/run": FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '{my_project_path}/run' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
null
```

So I created a flutter package instead with the same dependencies and class and when I now call

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

it works!

My dart version:

```
% dart --version                    
Dart VM version: 1.24.3 (Wed Dec 13 23:26:59 2017) on "macos_x64"
```

OS: macOS Big Sur
Version 11.6.7

And yes, I googled the problem extensively, but did not find anything related!

Any suggestions? Anyone? Please!

Edit:

Seems that my standalone dart installation is seriously broken. I can call `dart my_dart_program.dart` and it works. But if I try to call any dart commands like create, run, ... it looks for a file with this name in the current directory.

I changed my path settings to always use the dart version shipped with flutter and everything works just fine.

So I don't use the latest stable of dart for my dart only code, but I always know that everything is compatible with the current flutter version.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue but for me is working fine. Did this happen on many dart packages? or have you only tried the same one(same folder on your computer)?

Comment: Thank you Elian for trying to help. I think I somewhat found the issue, as you can see in my edited question.